# Can I safely upgrade to clang 6.0.0 for use with Xcode 9.0?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, installation, clang

I can build clang 6.0.0 following the instructions on the clang website, but I don't know where to safely install it or how to configure Xcode to use it.

I'm on macOS High Sierra.

Any help is appreciated.

---

This question was answered by: [How do I make Xcode use an alternative version of clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071024/how-do-i-make-xcode-use-an-alternative-version-of-clang)

The answer from MrMobster was perfect for me. The following post was also helpful:

[Compilation error when using Xcode 9.0 with clang (cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331918/compilation-error-when-using-xcode-9-0-with-clang-cannot-specify-o-when-genera)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Xcode use an alternative version of clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071024/how-do-i-make-xcode-use-an-alternative-version-of-clang)